# Filter function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I need help filter some data in Google Sheets. I want to create a `FILTER()` function that filters between 2 columns and also discards duplicates. Something like the `UNIQUE()` function between 2 columns.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D2:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B,C2:C="Q"))`

Another (perhaps simpler) way is to simply form a virtual array that selects the desired columns to be returned:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER({A2:A,D2:D},C2:C="Q"))`